# Delphi not updating Firebird database

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I have this code where if you come from the "create receipt" form it adds the product to a receipt and updates the main product correctly, but if I try to edit the receipt it does not save the updates, neither on the receipt nor the main product, even the

```pascal
ShowMessage('SQL Text: ' + MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('NewQuantity').AsString);
```

that I added to check if everything works shows the correct data and yet the database is not being updated.

Here is the code:

```pascal
procedure TNEProductForm.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewQuantity: Integer;
begin
  NewQuantity := 0;
  try
    if FSourceForm = 1 then
    begin
      // Update details in the "recipt_details" table using PurchaseID
      MDB.FDQuery1.SQL.Text :=
        'UPDATE "recipt_details" ' +
        'SET "ProductName" = :ProductName, "Price" = :Price, "Barcode" = :Barcode, "Quantity" = :Quantity ' +
        'WHERE "PurchaseID" = :PurchaseID';

      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('ProductName').AsString := edtProductName.Text;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Price').AsFloat := StrToFloat(edtPrice.Text);
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Barcode').AsString := edtBarcode.Text;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Quantity').AsInteger := StrToInt(edtQuantity.Text);
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('PurchaseID').AsInteger := FProductID;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

      NewQuantity := StrToInt(edtQuantity.Text) - OldQuantity;
    end
    else if FSourceForm = 2 then
    begin
      // Insert details into the "recipt_details" table using PurchaseID
      MDB.FDQuery1.SQL.Text :=
        'INSERT INTO recipt_details (PurchaseID, ProductName, Price, Barcode, Quantity) ' +
        'VALUES (:PurchaseID, :ProductName, :Price, :Barcode, :Quantity)';

      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('PurchaseID').AsInteger := FRecieptID;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('ProductName').AsString := edtProductName.Text;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Price').AsFloat := StrToFloat(edtPrice.Text);
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Barcode').AsString := edtBarcode.Text;
      MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Quantity').AsInteger := StrToInt(edtQuantity.Text);


      MDB.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
      NewQuantity := StrToInt(edtQuantity.Text);
    end;

    // Update product details in the database
    MDB.FDQuery1.SQL.Text :=
      'UPDATE Products ' +
      'SET ProductName = :ProductName, Barcode = :Barcode, ' +
      'Price = :Price, Quantity = Quantity + :NewQuantity ' +
      'WHERE ID = :ProductID';
    MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('ProductName').AsString := edtProductName.Text;
    MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Barcode').AsString := edtBarcode.Text;
    MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('Price').AsFloat := StrToFloat(edtPrice.Text);
    MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('NewQuantity').AsInteger := NewQuantity; // Use the calculated quantity
    MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('ProductID').AsInteger := FProductID;
    ShowMessage('SQL Text: ' + MDB.FDQuery1.ParamByName('NewQuantity').AsString);
    MDB.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;

    // Close both the NEProductForm and ProductListForm and indicate success
    ModalResult := mrOk;
    Close;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
  ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName VARCHAR(255),
  Price DECIMAL(10, 2),
  Quantity INT,
  Barcode VARCHAR(20)
);
    
CREATE TABLE Suppliers (
  ID INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(255),
  Address VARCHAR(255),
  Phone VARCHAR(20)
);
    
CREATE TABLE recipt (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- An auto-increment primary key for each purchase
  SupplierName VARCHAR(255),   -- Supplier name
  PurchaseDate DATE            -- Purchase date
);
    
CREATE TABLE recipt_details (
  ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, -- An auto-increment primary key for each product in the purchase
  PurchaseID INT,             -- Foreign key referencing the achats table
  ProductName VARCHAR(255),   -- Product name
  Price DECIMAL(10, 2),       -- Price of the product
  Barcode VARCHAR(50),        -- Barcode of the product
  Quantity INT                -- Quantity of the product
);
    
ALTER TABLE recipt_details
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_achat
  FOREIGN KEY (PurchaseID) REFERENCES recipt(ID);
    
CREATE GENERATOR gen_recipt_id;

SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_recipt FOR recipt
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(gen_recipt_id, 1);
END^
SET TERM ; ^

CREATE GENERATOR gen_recipt_details_id;
    
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_recipt_details FOR recipt_details
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(gen_recipt_details_id, 1);
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: I see no transaction commit. No changes survive rollback.

Comment: how do i commit the changes?

Comment: Naturally, calling "commit" method of the TFDTransaction. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Managing_Transactions_(FireDAC)

Comment: tried it, it did not work.

Comment: Update your question to include **where** you "_tried it_". Also: try spelling [rec**e**ipt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/receipt#Noun) correctly.

Comment: Are you sure of your FProductID ? This should be the value to test instead of NewQuantity.
Of subject : 
 - These StrtoInt and Strtofloat hurt my eyes
 -  recipt_details ProductName column also better should be ProductId with a foreign key contraint

Comment: P.S. ExecSQL returns a longint which is number of records changed so you can code

var r:=MDB.FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
care r of
  0 :  Showmessage('ExecSQL Fail on '+FProductId.ToString);
  else if r>1 then Showmessage('ExecSQL multiple rows updated');
end;